# Как наложить ограничение на столбец таблицы mysql?

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Есть таблица movies в ней есть столбец rate типа int. Как наложить ограничение, чтобы значение было меньше 6, но больше 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, MySQL не поддерживает проверочные ограничения CHECK. Значит остается триггер, либо проверять на клиенте.

Comment: можно ещё enum('1','2','3','4','5') :) правда будут возвращаться строки.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря не знаю, можно ли это сделать средствами mysql, но я бы это делал средствами языка, на котором написано приложение, использующая бд. Php, наверное, в вашем случае. Просто перед вставкой данных в таблицу проверяйте длину. Намного меньше проблем.